# Should bounties expire? How can I promote my bountied question even more?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

Why are bounties time bound? Clearly the site doesn't get enough traffic to ensure that in 7 days the appropriate users (who specialize in the domain of the question) would have stopped by Ask Ubuntu and stumbled upon the featured section.

Also, **[how can I promote my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923519/qtwebkit-on-ubuntu-17-04)**? I've put a 300 point bounty on it and it's been 4 days and only one person has even SEEN it.

I'm going to walk away from this thinking bounties are a glorified waste of points.

I suggest a new feature that bounties not expire. I don't see the harm. You lost the points anyways, and if someone ever comes along and answers, even past the seven days mark, they get a good reward in return, so everyone's happy.

Comment: Your question has 103 views and two people have commented on it repeatedly and responded to you, FTR

Comment: that's all  before the bounty

Comment: Hmmm. That's not good! I guess we are not looking at bounty questions enough any more...

Comment: I'm not a developer so can't answer your question, but [leaving a link to your question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/17048/revisions) in meta sometimes does the trick ...  Ping me here in the unlikely case the bounty cannot be awarded and I'll add 500 again which should give you 14 days total.

If that happens, I'll also be editing your question, because it's suffering from the TL;DR problem...

Comment: alright thanks very much. I'll probably edit it yeah it's a pick your poison : non-answers or TLDR

Comment: Heads-up that your bounty is about to expire. Disclaimer: I wrote an answer to the question.

Comment: @edwinksl omfg are you kidding me. I'm so sorry. I've been hospitalized since then I just got back to my home my leg is still in a cast this is a blasted turn of events because i wanted to give the points really badly. F**K! I'm so sorry! I'm looking at your answer now.

Comment: @tatsu Health is more important; don't worry about the bounty.

Comment: @edwinksl true. I can do the chat now if you want.